# Oracle connect via SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm using Oracle for learning purposes and faced with problem when I'm trying to connect user in SQL-plus command line.
[image]
Error

[image]

What is wrong? I did the setup according to the oracle tutorial.
And I have no problem with connection in SQL Developer.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Share output of `tnsping pdborcl` or `tnsping pdborc1`.

Comment: Umut TEKİN,
C:\Users\Max>tnsping pdborcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 24-JUL-2022 13:54:52

Copyright (c) 1997, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
W:\oracle\home\homes\OraDB21Home4\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

Comment: You don't appear to have `pdborcl` defined as an alias in your `tnsnames.ora`. You might [want to learn about this topic in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netag/identifying-and-accessing-database.html); particularly "understanding naming methods".

Comment: @Alex Poole, yeah, now I understand my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm finally resolve my problem. Thanks to @Umut TEKİN.

In my first setup I edited wrong tnsnames.ora file which was located in another path.
After using tnsping pdborcl command, I saw that oracle is looking for the name of the container(pdborcl) in another folder path `W:\oracle\home\homes\OraDB21Home4\network\admin\`.

After adding this

```
PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

into `W:\oracle\home\homes\OraDB21Home4\network\admin\tnsnames.ora` file I can connect without error.